# Project dynamic Dapper results excluding some properties

Tags: c#, linq, dapper

Given a dynamic Dapper query such as:

```
var results = connection.Query<dynamic>("SELECT ....");
```

I want to remove a couple of the returned columns/properties from the results. The trick is I want to do this without knowing/caring the names of the properties I want to keep, otherwise I would simply project the results into a new anonymous type.

I attempted to loop through the results and cast each to an `IDictionary<string, object>` so that I could simply remove the key/value pair holding the data. Unfortunately, for whatever reason, the underlying internal FastExpando object doesn't implement the Remove method. [The source code for FastExpando](https://github.com/SamSaffron/dapper-dot-net/blob/master/Dapper/SqlMapper.cs#L1303) shows:

```
bool IDictionary<string, object>.Remove(string key)
{
    throw new NotImplementedException();
}
```

How can I implement this? To be clear I basically want:

```
var filteredResults = from r in results
                      select new { // All properties except a couple of well-known ones }
```

Comment: Can you not exclude the well known properties at the SELECT query level?

Comment: I have no idea why we don't implement that! I'll ping Sam...

Comment: Alex, my specific use case is that I'm returning a paged set of data with an additional TotalResults column and a RowNumber column. While I need that data, I want to strip it out and then return the rest to the client in the form of JSON. The SQL that gets executed will always have these two columns, but the rest is unknown ahead of time.

Comment: I struggled with this until a coworker pointed out that after you use Linq on a dictionary you have an IEnumerable of KeyValuePair objects. This was causing problems for me when serializing the results. The solution for me was: 

    var resultsWithoutThatField = results.Select(row => ((IDictionary<string, dynamic>)row).Where(value => value.Key != thatField).ToDictionary(x => x.Key, x => x.Value));

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There was no reason that `FastExpandoObject` didn't implement those methods, other than: it hadn't needed to. I have now filled in all the missing / `NotImplementedException` methods. I haven't yet deployed to NuGet, but the code on github/google-code has been updated.

Answer (score 3):

What if you iterate the `FastExpandoObject` and return a filtered `ExpandoObject`?

```
 var filteredResults = dynamicResult.Select<dynamic, dynamic>(x =>
                    {
                        var filteredRow = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;
                        var props = x as IDictionary<string, object>;
                        foreach (var prop in props)
                        {
                            if (!filter.Contains(prop.Key))
                                filteredRow.Add(prop);
                        }
                        return filteredRow;
                    });
```